# Pull Chain Switch

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm a bit new to electronics/Arduino projects, so am looking for some help on some wiring needed for a project involving this Pull Chain: http://proto-pic.co.uk/pull-chain-switch/

The chain works like a fan chain would.

I am using an Arduino UNO

I have wired up the pull chain to a mini breadboard with a light that turns on and off just to test it's working. What I want to do, is get an analog/digital read each time the chain is pulled?

Is this possible? If so, would you be able to help me with how it would be wired up, as I am completely new to the electronics side of Arduino. I simply need to get a reading each time the chain is pulled, I don't need it to switch a light on.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Connect it between ground and an interrupt pin [configured as an input with the pullup enabled](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/pinMode). [Configure the interrupt](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt) to trigger on any state change. [Check the digital value of the pin](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/DigitalRead) in the ISR.